# Why does the Qt WebEngine Chromium build fail under MSVS Express 2015?

Tags: node.js, qt, qt5, chromium, qtwebengine

I'm trying to build Qt 5.7.0, and the build fails in the qtwebengine module. The bundled chromium doesn't build.

Things fail with a `gyp` error:

```
Could not locate Visual Studio installation.
```

What's wrong? Is there a workaround that doesn't involve installing the non-Express Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the MSVS version detection in the gyp tool used to build the bundled Chromium. See `qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\tools\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py`. The version detection doesn't know about MSVS 2015 Express.

You have to override the MSVS version detection. In the prompt where you build Qt, set:

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
```

If you have a batch file that sets up your build environment, the following does the trick:

```
@set V_VSVERSION=2015
@set V_VSCOMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
:: configure gyp overrides for msvs 2015 express
@if not exist "%V_VSCOMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\WDExpress.exe" goto no_vsexpress
@call :set_path V_VSEXPRESS "%V_VSCOMNTOOLS%\..\.."
@echo Info: Found MSVS Express %V_VSVERSION% at "%V_VSEXPRESS%"
@set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=%V_VSVERSION%
@set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=%V_VSEXPRESS%
:no_vsexpress

@exit /b

:set_path
@set %1=%~f2
@goto :eof
```